# How to use vue-twemoji-picker with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm trying using [vue-twemoji-picker](https://github.com/kevinfaguiar/vue-twemoji-picker) in my Vue + TypeScript project, but I'm getting an error below. How can I resolve this?

```
7:31 Could not find a declaration file for module '@kevinfaguiar/vue-twemoji-picker'. '/Users/owner/WebstormProjects/audilet/node_modules/@kevinfaguiar/vue-twemoji-picker/dist/vue-twemoji-picker.umd.min.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/kevinfaguiar__vue-twemoji-picker` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@kevinfaguiar/vue-twemoji-picker';`
     5 | 
     6 | <script lang="ts">
  >  7 | import { TwemojiPicker } from '@kevinfaguiar/vue-twemoji-picker';
       |                               ^
     8 | import {Component, Prop, Vue} from "vue-property-decorator";
     9 | 
    10 | @Component
```

I tried `yarn add -D @types/kevinfaguiar__vue-twemoji-picker`, but it returns not-found. (The vue-twemoji-picker project has `tsconfig.json` and `*.d.ts` files in its repository, so I believe this operation is not needed.)

My code:

```
<template>
  <div>test</div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { TwemojiPicker } from '@kevinfaguiar/vue-twemoji-picker';
import {Component, Prop, Vue} from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class SampleComponent extends Vue {
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your package you're using which does't generate the typing for exported things. Here's a few things that you could check a package has a built-in typing:

- Having a `index.d.ts` file at the root directory representing typing for the package
- Or the typing can be placed a different directory but in this case it must have to be addressed in the `typings` property in `package.json` file such as:

`package.json`

```json
{
  "typings": "typings/index.d.ts",
}
```

In short, if you're unable to see 2 above things, you can conclude a package having no built-in typing. So you have to define on your own as you've done or looking for it via `@types` repo.